Running into StackOverflowError when using retryWhen with WebFlux WebClient
I've attempted to create a webflux web client with built-in retry function for specific exceptions as for my use case, there are instances when the endpoint can be unavailable. With single failing requests the code seems to be working just fine, however under heavy, simulated load during the stress tests it ran into presumably infinite loop and threw StackOverflowError. This is the implementation of my function
private ExchangeFilterFunction retryFilterFunction(final Builder clientBuilder) {
  return (request, next) -> next.exchange(request)
    .retryWhen(globalRetryFunction(clientBuilder))
    .doOnError(throwable -> log.debug("Maximum retries exhausted for {}", clientBuilder.url));
}

Retry globalRetryFunction(final Builder clientBuilder) {
  return Retry.fixedDelay(clientBuilder.maxRetries, Duration.ofMillis(clientBuilder.delayBetweenRetries))
    .filter(throwable -> {
      final var exceptionCanonicalName = throwable.getClass().getCanonicalName();
      final var causeCanonicalName = throwable.getCause() != null
        ? throwable.getCause().getClass().getCanonicalName()
        : "";
      return webClientProperties.getExceptionsToRetry().contains(exceptionCanonicalName)
        || webClientProperties.getExceptionsToRetry().contains(causeCanonicalName)
        || clientBuilder.exceptionsToRetry.contains(exceptionCanonicalName)
        || clientBuilder.exceptionsToRetry.contains(causeCanonicalName);
    })
    .doBeforeRetry(retrySignal -> log.debug("Retrying for {} time", (retrySignal.totalRetries() + 1)));
}
 

and this is the stack trace that I get

Does anyone have a clue whether or not it's even possible to create a web client definition for webflux with built-in retry?
I've also managed to spot, that my retry keeps calling itself recursively with an ever increasing amount of recursive calls. Any clues on how to fix it?


looking at the stacktrace, my first guess is you are (somewhere) creating an endless loop.  have you checked those specific lines in your code?

Unfortunately this is not the case, because even for a simple call, that involves no loops, it still behaves the same

Stacktrace from line 4 and down. Whether it's in the code you wrote or not, whether it's a loop or recursive calls, there does seem to be an endless loop, which is usually the cause for a StackOverflow error.

Please se my edited answer, where it's now clear that the retryWhen keeps calling itself recursively
